# Concatenating in one column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2008.

Let's say I have these three tables:

**Product**

```
1, "Honda Civic" 
2, "Fiat Ritmo" 
3, "Ford Fiesta"
```

**ProductGroup**

```
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 3, 1
4, 2, 3
5, 2, 4
6, 1, 5
```

**Group**

```
1 American
2 Asian
3 European
4 Old
5 Fast
```

And let's say I want to query these tables so as to get the following:

```
"Fiat Ritmo", "European, Old"
"Honda Civic", "Asian, Fast"
"Ford Focus", "American"
```

How can I do this?

I'm using paging on the client side so I can't group the pages there.

Thanks for your help,

Barry

Comment: @OlegDok: minor implementation detail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FOR XML PATH feature to get string grouping like this:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)
INSERT @Product
VALUES(1, 'Honda Civic'), (2, 'Fiat Ritmo'), (3, 'Ford Fiesta')

DECLARE @ProductGroup TABLE(Product INT, Grp INT, PRIMARY KEY(Product, Grp))

INSERT @ProductGroup
VALUES 
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(3, 1),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(1, 5)

DECLARE @Grp TABLE(Id INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME NVARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Grp
VALUES
(1, 'American'),
(2, 'Asian'),
(3, 'European'),
(4, 'Old'),
(5, 'Fast')

SELECT p.name, 
(
    SELECT Name+','
    FROM @ProductGroup pg
    JOIN @Grp g
        ON pg.Grp = g.Id
    WHERE pg.Product = p.Id
    FOR XML PATH('')
) Groups
FROM @Product p
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Product
SELECT 1,'Honda Civic' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Fiat Ritmo' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Ford Fiesta'

DECLARE @ProductGroup TABLE(ID INT,ProductID INT, GroupID INT)
INSERT INTO @ProductGroup
SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1, 5

DECLARE @Group TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Group
SELECT 1, 'American' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Asian' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'European' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Old' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Fast'
```

Then the query:

```
SELECT
    Product.ID,
    Product.Name,
    STUFF
            (
            (
                SELECT 
                    ',' + Groups.Name
                FROM 
                    @ProductGroup AS ProductGroup
                    JOIN @Group AS Groups
                        ON ProductGroup.GroupID=Groups.ID
                WHERE 
                    ProductGroup.ProductID = Product.ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') AS Names
FROM
    @Product AS Product
```

Comment: No not at all. I read the question before you posted yours. Posted my answer and then I saw that you had almost the same answer. Then I up voted yours